# underscore contains (_.contains) on object types

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm just getting started with Javascript and using the Underscore library.  I see they have all sorts of utility function, like _.contains.  Is there a way to make this work on objects?

```
var indexes = [ {'id': 1, 'name': 'jake' }, {'id':4, 'name': 'jenny'},  {'id': 9, 'name': 'nick'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'jake' }, {'id':4, 'name': 'jenny'} ];

if (_.contains(indexes, {'id':1, 'name': 'jake'})) {
    console.log("contains");
}
```

Most of the examples they show have simple arrays with strings or numbers in them.  I was wondering what I can do to use their utility functions like _.contains for objects.  Thanks.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`contains` requires the values to be comparable with `===` which will not work with different instances of objects.

For instance it would work if you passed the exact object you are searching for, which isn't very useful.

```
if (_.contains(indexes, indexes[0])) {
```

You can however use `where` or `findWhere`.

```
if (_.findWhere(indexes, {'id':1, 'name': 'jake'})) {
```

`findWhere` is new in Underscore `1.4.4` so if you do not have it, you can use `where`.

```
if (_.where(indexes, {'id':1, 'name': 'jake'}).length > 0) {
```

Answer (score 14):

You would actually want to use [_.where](http://underscorejs.org/#where) for this.

```
var indexes = [ {'id': 1, 'name': 'jake' }, {'id':4, 'name': 'jenny'},  {'id': 9, 'name': 'nick'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'jake' }, {'id':4, 'name': 'jenny'} ];

if (_.where(indexes, {'id':1, 'name': 'jake'}).length) {
    console.log("contains");
}
```

Comment: You'd actually need to do `if(_.where(/*...*/).length)`, as `_.where` always returns an object.

Comment: _.findWhere() returns an object- _.where() returns an array- but i did forget a ".length"

Comment: yeah :) I didn't realize I forgot the ".length" until after I replied. Updated my answer